# Is it haram not to talk to my father?

Tags: halal-haram

I grew up with an alcoholic dad. He verbally abused me and my siblings and he hit my mom. I had a toxic relationship with him for 18 years of my life. I did grow up in an Islamic household but I furthered away from Islam and now I am getting closer and inshallah I will wear the hijab soon. but is it Haram not talk to him? he did ask to speak with me more than one time. I don't have it in my heart to talk to him or forgive him yet. I'm scared if I talk to him again I will further away from Islam and I don't want that to happen again.